# Client side validation in rails? Is there no hope?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, simple-form

Im using simple_form which im beginning to regret, simply (pun) because of the amount of work around you have to do to get anything done right.

Im using the latest verson of rails 4 and everythings going well except for client side validation on all of my forms.

I cant get Jquery validate to work and every single gem i can find is no longer supported.

This seems like such an easy problem to solve. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You don't need to use a gem written by someone else. If it's an easy problem to solve, just write the code to solve it!  You don't need to write that code as a general-purpose gem, you can just write what you need for your app, which will be simpler. Perhaps there are not any maintained general-purpose gems, because most people are just doing that.

Comment: client side javascript/jQuery has absolutely no knowledge of what server language or framework you use, and there is zero dependency. Why can't you add the code yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the asset pipeline and the order it pulled my .js files together.

I simply made controller .js files for each controller that utilizes validation and matched my model validations in java script.

For example in 'assets/javascripts/messages.js'

```
$('#message-form').validate({
debug: true,
rules: {
    'message[name]': {required: true, name: true},
    'message[sub]': {required: true},
    'message[notes]': {required: true}
}});
```

After that Rails is smart enough to do the rest.

You will have to make sure jquery validations is in the application.js reference